# How to make a program to reverse the sound of a wav clip and create a new wav file with the reversed audio in the C language

Tags: c, wav

This code generates the output file successfully but no sound actually, I don't know what's wrong yet

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "wav.h"
#include <string.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;

int check_format(WAVHEADER header);
int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    // TODO #1
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("usage: ./reverse input.wav output.wav\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open input file for reading
    // TODO #2
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("could not open file\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // Read header into an array
    // TODO #3
    WAVHEADER header;
    fread(&header, HEADER_SIZE, 1, input);

    // Use check_format to ensure WAV format
    // TODO #4

    if (check_format(header) == 5)
    {
        printf("Incorrect file format\n");
        return 3;
    }

    // Open output file for writing
    // TODO #5
    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        printf("could not open file\n");
        return 4;
    }

    // Write header to file
    // TODO #6
    fwrite(&header, HEADER_SIZE, 1, output);

    // Use get_block_size to calculate size of block
    // TODO #7
    int block_size = get_block_size(header);
    printf("block size is: %d\n", block_size);

    // Write reversed audio to file
    // TODO #8
    fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);
    long here = ftell(input);

    while (here > HEADER_SIZE)
    {
        int *Buffer[4];
        fread(Buffer, 4, 1, input);
        fwrite(Buffer, 4, 1, output);

        fseek(input, -4, SEEK_CUR);
        here -= 4;
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
}


int check_format(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #4
    BYTE *format = header.format;

    if (format[0] == 'W' && format[1] == 'A' && format[2] == 'V' && format[3] == 'E')
    {
        printf("is a wave file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Bad\n");
        return 5;
    }
}

int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #7
    int block_size = header.numChannels * (header.bitsPerSample / 8);
    return block_size;
}
```

I have already checked that it is an wav segment and print the header of the file, after that it is supposed to print each block from the input file to the output file starting from the end of the input file until reaching the header of the file (avoid printing the file header again), and I calculated the size of each block of the file .

We like to keep the order of channels for each audio block. For example, in a two-channel WAV file (stereophonic audio), we want to ensure that the first channel of the last input audio block becomes the first channel of the first output audio block.

Comment: You `fseek()` to the end of the input file, and then you start reading from it. What's the logic behind that? Because it won't work.

Comment: If you read 4 bytes, and then seek 4 bytes back, you'll read the same 4 bytes.

Comment: Also, the first 4 byte reads are from *beyond the end* of the file. Do the seek first. Always check that `fread` read what it was supposed to, from its return value. *Never* ignore that value.

Comment: Open the files excplicitly in binary mode `"rb"` and `"wb"`.

Comment: @EmanuelP 'code'fseek(input, -4, SEEK_CUR); This code is here to not read the same 4 bytes

Comment: It does. Reading 4 bytes moves the file pointer forwards 4 bytes, so you moved it back to *the same place*. You need to move it back by 8 bytes. Before the first iteration begins, move it back by 4 bytes (it starts beyond the end of the file). At the end of each loop, move it back 8 bytes.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm sorry, can you explain it with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this as an answer for the formatting, but I just want to explain a few things. When you open a file, that file has an associated position. That is like an index in the data. Using `fseek()` you can change this position, but when you simply `fread()` the position also increases.

Here you seek to the end, so a few lines later, you read *past* the end. There's no data there. So after that seek to the end, you should seek back 4 bytes. This ensures that you start with reading the last 4 bytes.

```
fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);
...
while (here > HEADER_SIZE)
{
    ...
    fread(Buffer, 4, 1, input);
    fseek(input, -4, SEEK_CUR);
```

Now, as you can see that read moves the position forward by 4, and then the seek moves it back by 4 as well. So you end up looping over the same bytes. Instead, you should seek back 8 bytes. The `here` variable is not affected by this, so you were right to decrease that with 4 every step.

Comment: Do I have to modify ftell inside the loop

Comment: No. `ftell` just gives you the position. You already used that to store the end position in the variable `here`. That part is fine.

Comment: "while (ftell(input) > HEADER_SIZE)
    {
        int *Buffer[4];
        fread(Buffer, 4, 1, input);
        fwrite(Buffer, 4, 1, output);

        fseek(input, -8, SEEK_CUR);
        ftell(input);
    }" I changed the values and the reversed sound was actually output, but the project is still not completed, it gives me an error message that the sound has not been reversed

Comment: Rome wasn't built in one day either :) You did the main part; the sound. Take a break, and if you encounter a new specific problem that you can't figure out, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
// declare array to store each block we read-in
// type array[size]
BYTE audioBlock[blockSize];
    
BYTE *lChannel = malloc(sizeof(blockSize / 2));
BYTE *rChannel = malloc(sizeof(blockSize / 2));

// seek pointer to lasst blockSize of input file
fseek(input, -(blockSize) - 1, SEEK_END);
int i = 1;
long int initFtell = ftell(input);
while (fread(audioBlock, sizeof(BYTE), blockSize, input) == blockSize)
{
    i += 1;
    long int k = (blockSize * i);
    memcpy(lChannel, audioBlock, blockSize / 2);
    memcpy(rChannel, &audioBlock[blockSize / 2], blockSize / 2);
    
    fwrite(rChannel, sizeof(BYTE), blockSize / 2, output);
    fwrite(lChannel, sizeof(BYTE), blockSize / 2, output);
    
    fseek(input, -(blockSize * i), SEEK_END);
    
    // printf("ftell: %li, k: %li\n", ftell(input), -k);
    if ((initFtell - k - HEADERSIZE) == 0) { break; } else { continue; }
}

// #9 close opened files
fclose(output);
fclose(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post helped me solve this task and pass the checker myself. A slight change that helped me with the breakthru was changing "4" to "block_size" like so, i hope the commentary provided helps to understand the logic here

```
    fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);
    long f_end = ftell(input);

    const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;
    while (f_end > HEADER_SIZE)
    {
        fseek(input, -block_size, SEEK_CUR);   // Moving the reading seeker a block back for reading

        int *Buffer[block_size];               // Buffer containg a block being read
        fread(Buffer, block_size, 1, input);   // Reading the block
        fseek(input, -block_size, SEEK_CUR);   // Moving past the read block
        fwrite(Buffer, block_size, 1, output);

        f_end -= block_size;
    }
```